Configure locale without PAM when connecting via SSH
I learned today that disabling PAM in sshd_config (UsePAM no) interferes with the locale setting (because /etc/default/locale is read by PAM), effectively making the system fall back from en_US.UTF-8 to POSIX. As I would like to keep PAM disabled for security reasons – is there a way to have configure the intended locale properly without PAM?
